# How do I get rid of a car that I own?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have a car in my garage that I don't want anymore. How can I make it so that it's not mine anymore?  Will destroying it do? Or just leaving it in the impound and letting them destroy it? The thing is that you can still claim the car back after it's been destroyed.  How do I permanently remove the possession of a car?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your car is not insured you can simply destroy it and you will be rid of it.

For insured cars it is a bit trickier:

- If your car is worth less than $50k you will be able to sell it to Los Santos Customs and get rid of it permanently that way.
- If the car exceeds that worth, you can replace it with another car when you have a full garage. Just drive a car from the streets into that garage, and you will get a warning that the garage is full and if you wish to replace a car. After the loading screen you will be prompted to choose a car for replacement.

Be careful with pressing the "OK"-button so as not to accidentally lose the first car on the list, if it is not the one you want replaced.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually sell vehicles to the Los Santos Customs, but only one every so often one every 45 mins

Answer (score 1):

Pull the car that you want to remove out of your garage, then call your mechanic and ask him to bring you another vehicle from your garage.  This will then destroy the vehicle, I found this out the hard way lol.

Comment: Has this since been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things:

1. Blow the cars up
2. Drive it into the ocean

There is no way to sell cars (at least not yet) so the only way to get rid of them is to turn the cars into scrap metal.

Comment: You can sell cars at LS Customs. I don't know about cars you own though, haven't tried it.

Comment: None of this permanently removes the car. You will still be able to reclaim in via insurance.

Comment: Unless the car isnt insured