# Can I sell my own expensive cars?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have an apartment with a 10 car garage. I have purchased 6 expensive cars and stored them in my garage, 4 of them I need to sell!

I want to buy a different apartment and I don't want to lose the cars I have. How do I sell the expensive cars I have already bought? Is there a garage option for this? I know I can't sell them to Los Santos Customs.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't sell the cars to Los Santos Customs because their individial worth exceeds 50k then you are out of luck. You will not be able to sell them anywhere. You will only be able to get rid of those cars when your garage has hit its limit and you will be asked to replace a car. [This question and its answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/133770/36641) are related to this problem.

On the topic of not loosing cars upon buying a new property, if you buy a property with the same amount of garage space it will not result in the loss of a car.
If you buy yourself a property with less garage space than the one you had before you will loose every car that is in the last few slots. As an example: When currently owning a 10 garage space property the first 6 cars in your garage are important and the last four are the ones you will loose upon buying a 6 garage space property.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sell premium super cars or anything over 50K.  The most expensive cars you can sell are like around 9K.

Comment: There are also cars worth 20K you can sell.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can sell cars I just sold one at Los santos customs but I think you can only do it if you are online