# In GTA Online, how do you get rid of your Annis Elegy RH8?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In GTA Online, I noticed that the Elegy RH8 shows up as "Free" when purchased on the Internet as a reward for signing up to the Rockstar Social Club.  I ended up buying 5 of them in different colors, all for free, but now they're taking up too much space in my garage.

How do I get rid of these cars?  Can I sell them?

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/133770/36641)

Comment: The accepted answer is no longer correct. See this [latest answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/388122/195013).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot sell them, they're a gift from Rockstar for being involved with the Rockstar Social Club.

If you're filling up your garage with them, just take them out and drive them into the ocean, blow them up, or simply leave them on the street.

If your garage is full, when you enter with another vehicle, it should prompt you for which vehicle you want to replace.

Comment: +1, I made the bad mistake of buying 8 of them (thinking I could sell them for more money).  Once I realized I couldn't sell them, I tried destroying them, but that became a problem whenever I had to call the insurance company (the 8 RH8s would all appear in that list of redeemable cars).  The only way I got rid them was that garage method.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a tip if you fall into the 'Elegy Hole' and want to keep a specific one (i.e. You have a custom you want to keep but lose the extras.)

This method uses the 'replace car' method. The nuance is that matching cars in the 'replace car' menu are listed identically. This method helps you identify a specific one using the police impound.

1. Take the Elegy you want to KEEP and get it impounded. (Have fun with this step).
2. Once your good Elegy is impounded go out into the world and fill your garage until it's full.
3. At the 11th car you'll be asked which car you want replaced. The Elegy you want to keep is safely stored in the impound and will say "(Impounded)" next to it in the replace car list.
4. Replace all the unwanted Elegys. (Elegi?)
5. Go to the impound and get your custom Elegy back. (Like a boss).

(Note: I suppose you could let the impounded Elegy be destroyed and file and insurance claim but what's the fun in that? "Go get that muthaf*cka, f*ck the police!")

Answer (score 3):

As of GTA Online Update 1.36 you can sell the free Elegy RH8s. You will not receive any money for a bare car but any modification you bought from LS Customs will be refunded at 50% price.

Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/5o32c1/just_realised_you_can_sell_the_elegy/)

Answer (score 2):

I got mine impounded then left it there to be destroyed